# moving everyone on discord on my VoiceChannel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello i'm coding right now with discord.py and i have problem with one command, about moving everyone to my channel.
For now i have something like this

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='moveall')
async def move_all(self, ctx):
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:
    for voice_channel in ctx.guild.voice_channels:
        if voice_channel is ctx.author.voice.channel:
            continue
        for member in voice_channel.members:
            member.voice.move_to(ctx.author.voice.channel)
```

but when i'm starting bot, i have problem :
ctx is required argument that is missing, and idk why it's show because im using it in command IF. Have someone idea how i can do it?

Comment: By any chance, do you have both a `discord.Client` object _and_ a `discord.ext.commands.Bot` object set up?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the command in a class (`Cog`) you shouldn't pass the `self` argument. Also you can use the `commands.has_permissions` decorator instead of that if-statement:

```py
@bot.command(name="moveall")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def move_all(ctx):
    for voice_channel in ctx.guild.voice_channels:
        if voice_channel is ctx.author.voice.channel:
            continue
        for member in voice_channel.members:
            member.move_to(ctx.author.voice.channel)
```

Another thing is that there's no such thing as `member.voice.move_to` it's `member.move_to`